# Filipino Citizen with Europe visa holder

Tags: filipino-citizens

My husband and are i both Filipino citizen with a philippine passport  and will travel home to philippines from Norway with almost 11hrs lay over in Incheon South Korea. We both have a valid Norwegian residence visa. Do we need a visa for us to go out from the airport?Thank you.